# Invoke WCF SoapService method cause exception if input string contains html or xml

Tags: c#, html, xml, wcf, soap

I create a method to receive json string, the method definition is below:

```
[OperationContract]
string AccessAtomService(string cmd);
```

It works when I invoke this method by following input:

```
{
  "receivers": [
    "kevin.chan@xxx.com"
  ],
  "subject": "Notification",
  "isHtml": false,
  "content": "Test ok",
  "serviceName": "xxx"
}
```

But the following json input causes exception:

```
{
  "receivers": ["kevin.chan@xxx.com"],
  "subject": "EMS3000 Notification",
  "isHtml": false,
  "content":"<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>",
  "serviceName": "xxx"
}
```

It seems that any xml element in my json string  would cause exception,
the exception message from WCF tarce log is:

> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

First StackTrace item is:

> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding your content before sending it to the service:

```
 {
"receivers": ["kevin.chan@xxx.com"],
"subject": "EMS3000 Notification",
"isHtml": false,
"content":"&lt;a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com/html/\"&gt;Visit our HTML tutorial&lt;/a&gt;",
"serviceName": "xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because WCF serializes using XML.

So the string you are using is messing with the Deserialization.

[MSDN WCF Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073(v=vs.110).aspx)